# Add more than one page owner to a page in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, access

Is it possible to add more than one page owner to a page in SharePoint 2007. I have a page where 3 people need to have access to it for updating purposes.

Comment: What do you mean add them as a page owner? Do you just mean 3 people need to have access but everyone is restricted to read or no access?